# Script não continua a execução

Tags: javascript, html

Estou fazendo um script que recolha os dados dos alunos que são exibidos apenas em uma página  HTML.

As tags não são identificadas por *id*, e tive que recolher tudo de uma forma bem inadequada (buscando a tag `<strong>` por exemplo). Porém, após buscar os dados na página `function buscaDados()`, o script não continua para a próxima função que é a `listaDados()`.

Não consegui identificar o erro.

Aqui o HTML:

```
 <table><tbody><tr><td>
        Matricula: 1011<br> Situação <br><strong>INATIVO</strong>
        </td><td>
<table><tbody><tr>
        <td>Nome<br><strong>Fábio Gonçalves</strong></td>
      </tr><tr><td>Rua das Amoras, 515<br><strong><span style="color:#28858C;">Não possui veículo cadastrado</span> </strong></td>
      </tr></tbody></table></td>
        <td valign="top"><table><tbody><tr>
<td>Email<br><strong>Divulgação não autorizada</strong></td></tr><tr>
        <td>Nascimento<br><strong>Divulgação não autorizada </strong></td></tr>
    </tbody></table></td></tr>     
      <tr><td><strong>Ativo desde 01/03/2014</strong></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

E o script:

```
<script>
var tabela = [];
var i = 0;
var indiceCRM = 0;
var qtdeCadastros = 0;
var posicao = 0;
var todoHtml = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML;
var j = 0;
var html = "<table>";
buscaDados();
listaDados();
function pegaCRM(posicao){
    posicao = todoHtml.indexOf("CRM:");
    var texto = todoHtml.substr(posicao, 11);
    tabela.push(texto);
    todoHtml = todoHtml.substr(posicao+11,10000000);//Considerando matrículas com 11 Caracteres
    posicao = posicao+11;
    return posicao;
  }

  function verificaMesmoCadastro(verificador){
    if(!verificador){var verificador = true;
    var verifica = document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[i+1].innerText;
    if(verifica ==="ATIVO"){verificador = false;}
    else if(verifica==="INATIVO"){verificador = false;}
    return verificador;}
    if(verificador){return true;}}    

  function buscaDados(){
    while(qtdeCadastros<=10){
          var status = document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[i].innerText;
          tabela.push(status);
          console.log(status);
          posicao = pegaCRM(posicao); 
          while(verificaMesmoCadastro(false)){
            var dado = document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[i+1].innerText;
            console.log(dado);
            tabela.push(dado);
            i++;
          }
          if(!verificaMesmoCadastro(false))i++;
          console.log(qtdeCadastros);
          qtdeCadastros++;
    }
  }

  function listaDados(){
      for(reg=0;reg<10;reg++){
          html+="<tr>";
          while(tabela(j+1)==="ATIVO"||tabela[j+1]==="INATIVO"){
              html+="<td>"+tabela[j]+"</td>";
              j++;
          }
          html+="</tr>";
          j++;
      }
      html+="</table>";
      document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML=html;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Algum erro na consola? Acho `while(verificaMesmoCadastro(false)){` meio perigoso, fácil de ter um erro e ser dificil debugar. O que queres fazer com essa linha?

Comment: Aparece que tem um erro em:
var verifica = document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[i+1].innerText;

Erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined.

Eu quero que o while seja executado apenas quando o valor buscado no html NÃO seja "ATIVO" ou "INATIVO", pois quando esse valor aparecer, significa que começaram os dados do próximo aluno.

Comment: Esse erro é porque o i+1 ta dando um número de posição no array que não existe.

Comment: Há muitos erros nesse código, precisavas de passar por um ESLint. Esta linha`if(!verificador){var verificador = true;` está a re-declarar a variável. É isso que queres? Outra coisa: chamar `while(verificaMesmoCadastro(false)){` vai sempre fazer `verificaMesmoCadastro()` retornar true, e criar um loop infinito. Cria um exemplo que mostre o problema no jsFiddle, ou no widget do Stackoverflow para ficar mais claro.